# Laravel - 'array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array' occurring when i'm not using an array anymore

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I was using arrays to pass data back to a view from a controller, but now have switched to using just strings, however this error pops up.

" array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array "

I'm not even using an array anymore, and i've done php artisan clear:cache incase there was some cache I didn't know about. I'm new to laravel but all the results I find are dealing with people incorrectly using arrays, whereas i'm just passing a simple string.

Can somebody please help? Below is my code

**section of code in controller**

```
else {
                $result = 'That email belongs to an existing referrer.';
                return view('admin.invalidReferrer', $result);
```

**section of code in invalidReferrer.blade.php**
    @extends('admin.admin')

```
@section('results')

<h4>{{ $result }}</h4>


@stop
```

**previous controller solution**

```
else {
    $result = ['That email belongs to an existing referrer.'];
    return view('admin.invalidReferrer', compact('result'));
```

**previous blade solution**

```
@section('results')

<h4>{{ $result[0] }}</h4>

@stop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the previous solution but remove the superfluous array assignment.

Instead of using:

```
$result = ['That email belongs to an existing referrer.']; // shorthand array assignment of string to index 0
// ^ unneeded array assignment ^
```

Just assign the string directly:

```
$result = 'That email belongs to an existing referrer.';
return view('admin.invalidReferrer', compact('result'));
```

Then use the imported data normally as you would:

```
@section('results')

<h4>{{ $result }}</h4>

@stop
```

Comment: @Unifx the OP maybe doesn't know that `[]` is an array assignment, but directly using it inside the second argument works fine too

Comment: Thank you for the responses.

I tried that before and it worked, but doesn't compact() return the variable(s) as an array which is still less efficient than passing back a string?

Comment: @AndrewMMG but you can't directly pass a single string inside `view` as you can't delegate a simple string inside after passing a view. its needs to be inside a key pair value. either use `compact` or use `['result' => 'string here']`

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for the insight. In the laravel documentation it had an example where it just used return view('name', $data) so I was operating under the assumption that I could.

Is either of those solutions more efficient than the other? eg: is using a key pair value more efficient than using compact?

Comment: @AndrewMMG i don't think it has any difference at all expect that one is a function and one is another plain array assignment. and most likely `$data` inside the example contains key pair values. you can't directly pass a single lone string, it needs to be an array. just follow the API, it already says there

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.html#method_view, it already says there, second argument needs an array

Answer (score -1):

Just follow this instructions:

1. Remove **config.php** and **service.php** file from bootstrap.
2. run **php artisan serve**
3. run **ctrl+c** on terminal after **php artisan serve**
4. and run **composer update**

fixed for me.